# Анимация Margin.Top

Tags: c#, wpf

```
DoubleAnimation TopAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
            TopAnim.From = Search.Margin.Top;
            TopAnim.To = 100;
            TopAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            TopAnim.BeginAnimation(TextBox.MarginProperty,TopAnim);
```

Ругается нельзя анимировать отступы.
А надо перемесить элемент в низ

Comment: Позиционирование элементов маргинами само по себе неправильная вещь. Например, оно часто плохо себя ведёт при изменении размеров окна. Расскажите, какого эффекта вы хотите добиться.

Comment: сместить вверх в тесчение 1 секунды

Comment: Сместить временно или надолго? И зачем именно сместить?